# OpenGL color picker/variable or field ‘glReadPixels’ declared void

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm attempting to make a color picker in OpenGL for a program I'm writing.
I keep getting the error "variable or field ‘glReadPixels’ declared void"
I have researched and can not find what the error means which makes it difficult to correct.

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#  include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#  include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#  include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#  include <GL/gl.h>
#  include <GL/glu.h>
#  include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#define WIDTH 750
#define HEIGHT 750

int i=0,mousex, mousey;

unsigned char pick[3];

float A = pick[0]/255;
float B = pick[1]/255;
float C = pick[2]/255;

bool mouseleftdown = false;



void hex(void){
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);           //red
    glVertex2f(0, 2);           //top
    glColor3f(1,.38,.01);       //orange
    glVertex2f(2, 1);           //top right
    glColor3f(1,1,0);           //yellow
    glVertex2f(2, -1);          //bottom right
    glColor3f(0,1,0);           //green
    glVertex2f(0, -2);          //bottom
    glColor3f(0,0,1);           //blue
    glVertex2f(-2, -1);         //bottom left
    glColor3f(.8,0,.8);         //purple
    glVertex2f(-2, 1);          //top left
glEnd();

glEnd();
}

void square(void){
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex2i(1, -1);
glVertex2i(1, 1);
glVertex2i(-1, 1);
glVertex2i(-1, -1);
glEnd();
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
// Save the left button state
if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
{
    mouseleftdown = (state == GLUT_DOWN);
    glutPostRedisplay();  // Left button has changed; redisplay!
}

// Save the mouse position
mousex = x;
mousey = y;

}

void glReadPixels(mousex , mousey , 1 , 1 , GL_RGB , GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE , pick);


void draw(void){
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(A,B,C);
glScalef(750,750,1);
square();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glScalef(20,20,1);
    hex();
glPopMatrix();

glFlush();

}

void my_init(void){
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);               //sets clear color
glLineWidth(4);
gluOrtho2D(-100, 100, -100, 100);       //sets origin
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[ ]){
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
glutCreateWindow("Color Picker");
glutDisplayFunc(draw);
glutMouseFunc(mouse);

my_init();

glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);

glutMainLoop();                         //listens for events

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting the line with `glReadPixels` on it to do? It's not in any function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the keyword `void` from in front of the call to `glReadPixels`, then move it so that it's inside a function at the place you want to call it, presumably inside `mouse()` inside the left-click `if` block.

Comment: I did that but It still isn't running properly. I am getting a question mark whenever I cout the array that should be holding the RGB values.

Comment: How are you printing out the array?